# what does "-- --ci" mean in node.js script: "npm run test:unit -- --ci"

Tags: node.js, npm

I saw some node.js scripts have "--" option, for example `npm run test:unit -- --ci`

What does "--ci" and "--" options mean?

Comment: See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script then the docs for whatever binary `test:unit` is actually running.

Comment: Found out what's the "--ci" CLI option on Jest:

When this option is provided, Jest will assume it is running in a CI environment. This changes the behavior when a new snapshot is encountered. Instead of the regular behavior of storing a new snapshot automatically, it will fail the test and require Jest to be run with --updateSnapshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special option -- is used by getopt to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the -- directly to your script:

npm run test -- --grep="pattern"
The arguments will only be passed to the script specified after npm run and not to any pre or post script.

[Source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script)